# Java optional: map to subclass or else super class

Tags: java, scala, akka, option-type, akka-http

I am trying to re-write a scala example of a POC project from Manning's "Akka in Action" in Java. The project is a small Http server for creating events and buying tickets.

I am at a point when an actor can send an `Optional<Event>` to my `RestApi`. Depending on whether the value is present I should complete the call with `OK`, else `NOT_FOUND`.

In Scala the snippet looks as follow:

```
      get {
          // GET /events/:event
          onSuccess(getEvent(event)) {
            _.fold(complete(NotFound))(e => complete(OK, e))
          }
        }
```

...where `getEvent` returns an `Option[Event]` (equivalent of java's `Optional<Event>`). This is how I rewrote it in Java:

```
   get(() -> onSuccess(() -> getEvent(event), eventGetRoute()))

   ...
    //and eventGetRoute() is a function:
    private Function<Optional<Event>, Route> eventGetRoute() {
        return maybeEvent -> maybeEvent.map(event -> complete(OK, event, Jackson.marshaller())).orElseGet(() -> complete(NOT_FOUND));
    }
```

This doesn't compile: `Bad return type in lambda expression: Route cannot be converted to RouteAdapter`. The longer (and first) `complete` returns a `RouteAdapter` and the second one returns a `Route`. If I re-write the above function like this:

```
private Function<Optional<Event>, Route> eventGetRoute() {
    return maybeEvent -> {
        if(maybeEvent.isPresent()) {
            return complete(OK, maybeEvent.get(), Jackson.marshaller());
        }
        return complete(NOT_FOUND);
    };
}
```

...then the compiler doesn't complain, but then it is not right way to map an Optional.

Java doesn't have `fold` method for Optional (not in SE8 at least), which allows passing the fallback-to value first.

I'm curious whether it is possible to write this function in respecting functional style.

**Update**:

As asked in the comments, these are the signatures of the `complete` methods from `akka-http` javadsl library:

```
  def complete(status: StatusCode): Route = RouteAdapter(
    D.complete(status.asScala))
```

and

```
  def complete[T](status: StatusCode, value: T, marshaller: Marshaller[T, RequestEntity]) = RouteAdapter {
    D.complete(ToResponseMarshallable(value)(fromToEntityMarshaller(status.asScala)(marshaller)))
  }
```

Comment: Please share the basic signatures of the overloaded method `complete` to complete the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is return type of `complete(OK, maybeEvent.get(), Jackson.marshaller())`?

I assume `RouteAdapter`. If so cast it to `Route` so chain will be binded to `Route` not `RouteAdaper` and at the end will not have troubles with casting from super class to subclass.

Comment: Indeed that was the closest I could have guessed as well, just not much idea about the library in use.

Comment: Thanks for this hint Alexander! Excellent :-) With a `(Route)` in front of first `complete` the compiler is happy.